# Accessing "Public" methods from "Private" methods in javascript class

Tags: javascript, oop, private, public

Is there a way to call "public" javascript functions from "private" ones within a class?

Check out the class below:

```
function Class()
{
    this.publicMethod = function()
    {
        alert("hello");
    }

    privateMethod = function()
    {
        publicMethod();
    }

    this.test = function()
    {
        privateMethod();
    }
}
```

Here is the code I run:

```
var class = new Class();
class.test();
```

Firebug gives this error:

**publicMethod is not defined: [Break on this error] publicMethod();**

Is there some other way to call publicMethod() within privateMethod() without accessing the global class variable [i.e. class.publicMethod()]?

Comment: I hope it's just a typo in your example here, but your `privateMethod` is a global variable.

Comment: In Firefox if I call `class.privateMethod()` there is an error whereas `class.publicMethod()` works fine, so it seems like there is some difference between the two functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer has the possibly undesirable side effect that separate copies of `publicMethod`, `test`, and `privateMethod` will be created in each instance. The idiom for avoiding this is:

```
function Class()
{}

Class.prototype=(function()
{
    var privateMethod = function(self)
    {
        self.publicMethod();
    }


    return 
    {
        publicMethod: function()
        {
            alert("hello");
        },
        test: function()
        {
            privateMethod(this);
        }
    };
}());
```

In other words, you need to pass the `this` to the private function as an argument. In return, you get a **true** prototype without having to pollute each instance with its own versions of the private and public functions.

Comment: Nice! Rather than pass in, you could always `privateMethod.call(this)` too

Answer (score 8):

You can save off a variable in the scope of the constructor to hold a reference to `this`.

**Please Note:** In your example, you left out `var` before `privateMethod = function()` making that `privateMethod` global.  I have updated the solution here:

```
function Class()
{
  // store this for later.
  var self = this;
  this.publicMethod = function()
  {
    alert("hello");
  }

  var privateMethod = function()
  {
    // call the method on the version we saved in the constructor
    self.publicMethod();
  }

  this.test = function()
  {
    privateMethod();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

torazaburo's answer is the best one, as it avoids creation of multiple copies of the private members. I'm surprised that Crockford doesn't mention it at all. Alternately, depending on the syntax you prefer for declaring public member functions, you could do this:

```
function Class()
{}

(function() {
    var privateMethod = function(self) {
        self.publicMethod();
    };

    Class.prototype.publicMethod = function() {
        alert('hello');
    };

    Class.prototype.test = function() {
        privateMethod(this);
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this approach not a advisable one? I am not sure though

```
var klass = function(){
  var privateMethod = function(){
    this.publicMethod1();
  }.bind(this);

  this.publicMethod1 = function(){
    console.log("public method called through private method");
  }

  this.publicMethod2 = function(){
    privateMethod();
  }
}

var klassObj = new klass();
klassObj.publicMethod2();
```